# Problem with keyboard mappings using IRB and Rails Installer under Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, irb

I'm having a problem setting up the Rails Installer package under Windows - when IRB has been fired up, it seems to zap the default keyboard mappings which breaks the backspace function.

It's appearing in the console as what I *think* is a Crtl-D character - or at least, it's displaying as <-[D.   IRB also seems to have lost the Crtl-H backspace mapping as well.

Has anyone come across this - or even better, come across a fix?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
ruby -S irb
```

or

```
alias irb='ruby -S irb'
```

workaround via Luis Lavena at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rubyinstaller/HgswOz1T-eE/DgBH6PMpRPEJ

bug reported at https://github.com/luislavena/rb-readline/issues/37